# What will happen when i update table with same values again and again?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers, updates

What will happen when i update table with same values again and again?
Ex :

> update tblExample set Col1 =1214 where Id=17

lets assume i keep updating this record with same value without changing any columns. 
how the execution will happen?
What will happen when we do this in **After Update** trigger?

Comment: I'm pretty sure SQL Server  updates the row without checking the existing values, so triggers are triggered and so on even when the data doesn't change.

Answer (score 3):

If you run an `UPDATE` statement, that `UPDATE` statement will be run (surprise), even if the values you are setting the columns to are the same value. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test (ID int, SomeString varchar(10));

INSERT INTO dbo.test
VALUES(1,'abc'),
      (2,'def');
GO
--Will return 1 row updated
UPDATE dbo.test
SET SomeString = 'abc'
WHERE ID = 1;
GO
--Will return 1 row updated
UPDATE dbo.test
SET SomeString = 'abc'
WHERE ID = 1;
GO
```

When you run those `UPDATE` statments, the value of `SomeString` is still set. If you therefore have a trigger on `UPDATE` on that table, it's still going to trigger, and do whatever it would do normally. If you don't want it to, you'd need to check against the values of the columns in `inserted` and `deleted` to see if it differs.

To expand further, here's a little demo with a trigger (note that, normally having a `SELECT` statement that returns a dataset in a trigger is bad, and (if I recall correctly) was a deprecated feature in SQL Server 2017).

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.test_trg ON dbo.test
AFTER UPDATE AS

    SELECT *
    FROM inserted; --SELECTs in triggers are bad!

GO
--Will perform the SELECT in the trigger
UPDATE dbo.test
SET SomeString = 'abc'
WHERE ID = 1;
GO
--Instead, check is the value is different
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.test_trg ON dbo.test
AFTER UPDATE AS

    SELECT i.*
    FROM inserted i
         JOIN deleted d ON i.ID = d.ID
    WHERE i.SomeString != d.SomeString; --SELECTs in triggers are bad!

GO
--Won't return any rows
UPDATE dbo.test
SET SomeString = 'abc'
WHERE ID = 1;
--Will return a row
UPDATE dbo.test
SET SomeString = 'bcd'
WHERE ID = 1;
GO
--Cleanup
DROP TABLE dbo.test;
```